# Twitter4j not work on JSF

Tags: jsf, twitter4j

I develop an app and for login od like to use  sign in with Twitter.
I can get access token but then i cant get any user id/screen name.
I got 401:Authentication credentials. If i put this twitter object to session, its not working. Cant find any jsf example.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
    <f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="oauth_token" value="#{test.oauth_token}" />
    <f:viewParam name="oauth_verifier" value="#{test.oauth_verifier}" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{test.yaz()}" />
    </f:metadata>
    <h:outputText value="#{test.oauth_token}"></h:outputText>
    <h:form>
    <p:commandButton id="addUser" value="Add"
                        action="#{test.getToken()}" ajax="false" /> 
    </h:form>   
    </h:body>
    </html>

<pre>
<code>

        package temp;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.util.Map;
        import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
        import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
        import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
        import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
        import twitter4j.Twitter;
        import twitter4j.TwitterException;
        import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
        import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
        import twitter4j.auth.RequestToken;
        import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;
        @ManagedBean(name="test")
        @RequestScoped
        public class TestOath {
        String oauth_token;
        String oauth_verifier;
        String request_token;
        String request_token_secret;
        Twitter twitter;
        public String getRequest_token() {
            return request_token;
        }
        public String getRequest_token_secret() {
            return request_token_secret;
        }
        public void setRequest_token(String request_token) {
            this.request_token = request_token;
        }
        public void setRequest_token_secret(String request_token_secret) {
            this.request_token_secret = request_token_secret;
        }
        public String getOauth_verifier() {
            return oauth_verifier;
        }
        public void setOauth_verifier(String oauth_verifier) {
            this.oauth_verifier = oauth_verifier;
            System.out.println("setOauth_token="+oauth_verifier);
        }
        public String getOauth_token() {
                return oauth_token;
        }
        public void setOauth_token(String oauth_token) {
            System.out.println("setOauth_token="+oauth_token);
            this.oauth_token = oauth_token;
        }
        public TestOath(String oauth_token) throws IOException {

        this.oauth_token = oauth_token;

        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
        return "TestOath [oauth_token=" + oauth_token + "]";
        }
        public TestOath() {
        super();
        }

        public void getToken() throws IOException{

        String returnText="";
         try {
            ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
             cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
                     .setOAuthConsumerKey("my apps consumer key")
                       .setOAuthConsumerSecret("my apps consumer secret")
                     .setOAuthAccessToken(null)
                     .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(null);
             TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
             this.twitter = tf.getInstance();
             RequestToken requestToken = this.twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
             System.out.println("Got request token.");
             System.out.println("Request token: " + requestToken.getToken());
             System.out.println("Request token secret: " +    requestToken.getTokenSecret());
             ExternalContext externalContext =  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
             externalContext.redirect(requestToken.getAuthorizationURL());

             System.out.println("Test OAUTH is DONE");
             FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("yourKey", this.twitter);

         }
         catch(TwitterException t){

         }
             }

        public void yaz() throws TwitterException
        {
            System.out.println("111");
            if(this.oauth_token == null)
            {
                System.out.println("not have any access code");
            }
            else
            {
                ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
                        .setOAuthConsumerKey("i put my  apps consumer key")
                        .setOAuthConsumerSecret("i put my apps consumer secret")
                        .setOAuthAccessToken(this.oauth_token)
                        .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(this.oauth_verifier);
                TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
                Twitter t = tf.getInstance();
                System.out.println(t.getId());
            }
            return ;
                }    
        public void parameterOnLoad(FacesContext fc) {
            Map<String,String> params = fc.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

        String oauth_token = params.get("oauth_token");
        System.err.println("oauth_token="+oauth_token);
       }

    }

</code><pre>
```

Comment: Is there a specific problem other than saying "not working"?

Comment: I cant use session values. All of them return null. I changed my scope to SessionScope but again its not working.                                                               Warning: Unable to restore sessions for web module [/JSFSpringHibernatePrimeFaces] from previous deployment
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: twitter4j.HttpParameter